# Python - socket server that allows connections from other networks (Port Forwarding? UPnP?)

Tags: python, sockets

How can I create a socket server that allows connections from other networks?

Currently, my server is running on my IPv4 address. This works fine. However, the server cannot be connected to from other networks. I know you can do port forwarding to get this to work, but how can I make the script automatically do port forwarding?

Here is my server code:

```py
import socket, pickle
from _thread import *
from serverside import Player, get_chest_tiles
from maps import maps

server = '10.0.0.187'
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)

s.listen()
print(f'Server started with address: {server}, on port: {port}\nWaiting for connections...')


players = []
zombies = [False]
current_map = maps['town']
chest_tiles = get_chest_tiles(current_map[0])

def threaded_client(conn, player):
    players.append(Player())
    conn.sendall(pickle.dumps([players[player], player]))
    while True:
        reply = []
        players_reply = []
        try:
            data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(999999))
            if type(data) == list:
                if data[0] == 'UPDATE_ZOMBIES':
                    global zombies
                    zombies = data[1]
                elif data[0] == 'UPDATE_MAP':
                    global current_map
                    current_map = data[1]
            else:
                players[player] = data

            if not data:
                break
            else:
                for p in range(len(players)):
                    if p < player or p > player:
                        players_reply.append(players[p])

                reply = [players_reply, current_map, zombies, chest_tiles]

            conn.sendall(pickle.dumps(reply))
        except:
            break

    print('Lost connection')
    players.pop(player)
    conn.close()

currentPlayer = 0
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected to:', addr)

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, currentPlayer))
    currentPlayer += 1
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/UPnPy/1.0.3/

Comment: @FrankYellin how can I use this to do what I'm trying to do?